# Control Lego Technic Control+ Hub via Python

Tags: technic, software, python, control-plus

Is it possible to control the Lego Technic Control+ Hub with Python?

I have tried using [Pybricks](https://code.pybricks.com) but that didn't work well for me.

Comment: Hi Luftiger and welcome to Bricks.SE! You wrote that using Pybricks didn't work well for you, could you please provide more details on what have you tried and how did that fail? As far as I know, many people are using it successfully, so it should be worth a while to find the cause why it didn't for you.

Comment: Hello zovits! Every time I try I get an Error that Connection Failed for Unknown Reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to remote control a Technic Control+ hub with Python using a library such as [pylgbst](https://github.com/undera/pylgbst) or [bricknil](https://github.com/virantha/bricknil).

You can also write MicroPython programs that run on the hub directly using [Pybricks](https://pybricks.com).

You can get support for Pybricks at https://github.com/pybricks/support/discussions. There is a [Bluetooth troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/pybricks/support/discussions/270) to help with connection issues.